# Complex polynomial roots within the unit circle

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Consider the complex poynomial 
$$P(z)=z^{n+1}-z^n+\epsilon c$$
with positive integer $n$, real $\epsilon>0$ and complex $c$ with $Re(c)>0$.  I am interested in finding explicit upper bounds on $\epsilon$ such that all roots lie within the unit circle.

An answer for the special case $n=1$ has been given in [my earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687590/roots-within-the-unit-circle) by @dxiv.